# How synchronized method with composite objects works

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I am curious whether the next code fragment is thread safe, especially focusing on the synchronized keyword with composite objects. In case the **updateAge** happens before **getB** will the second caller receive the updated value of age?

In case the answer is yes, please explain how the JVM performs that? (I assume that the JVM code must flush the accessed objects when exiting the synchronized method/block to the main memory, is the JVM code extract all referenced objects from the root object?)

```
public class A {

    private B b;

    public B getB() { return b; }

    public void setB(B b) { this.b = b; }
}

public class B {

    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Integer getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(Integer age) { this.age = age; }
}

public class Main {

    private A a;

    public Main() {
        a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        b.setName("name");
        b.setAge(10);
        a.setB(b);
    }

    public synchronized void updateAge(Integer age){ a.getB().setAge(age); }

    public synchronized B getB() { return a.getB(); }
}
```

**Update 1:**

Is the alternative class is equivalent to the original Main class above? Since ConcurrentMap performs synchronization during put. Ignore the case were 2 concurrent threads call *updateAge* method.

```
public class Main2 {

    private ConcurrentMap<String, A> store = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    public Main2() {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        b.setName("name");
        b.setAge(10);
        a.setB(b);

        store.put("id", a);
    }

    public void updateAge(Integer age){
        A a = store.get("id");
        a.getB().setAge(age);
        store.put("id", a);
    }

    public B getB() { return store.get("id").getB(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by thread safety. If the system consists of just these two methods, then the answer is yes, this is thread-safe as any changes made by `updateAge()` will be visible to callers to `getB()`.

However since `getB()` returns a mutable instance of `B`, there's nothing stopping me writing something like this:

```
Main main = ...;
main.updateAge(42); // we change the age of B in a synchronized block
B myLittleB = main.getB(); //this is synchronized to the same object, so it's all fine
myLittleB.setName("Boaty McBoatface"); //this isn't synchronized so if another thread calls main.getB().getName(), all bets are off
```

**Update:** How visibility guarantees are fulfilled depends on VM implementation and architecture, but there are several alternative strategies available, for example runtime code analysis to establish which variables can potentially change in the synchronized block, or even flushing everything without discrimination.